# Can not understanding PHP associative array code difference in below codes

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, shopping-cart

I have this code in my Shopping Cart. I got this from a site. I am using this and code is working fine but i can not understand the difference between the `first code` and the `second code`. It seems both are same to me. But if i use only the first code in the place of second code then my `cart` doesn't work right. So can anyone tell me what is the difference between them??

`First code:`

```
$cart = [
          $id => [
                'name' => $product->name,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'price' => $product->price,
                'photo' => $product->image
               ]
       ];
```

`Second code:`

```
$cart[$id] = [
            'name' => $product->name,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'photo' => $product->image
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code replaces, whatever was in `$cart` before, with a new array. This means that any previous value of `$cart` is forgotten.

The second code **only** adds a new key-value pair into the array, or replaces that key-value pair if it already existed. This means that other key-value pairs will not be forgotten.

I assume the `$id` is a product identifier. The first code will only allow one product in your cart, whereas the second code allows many different products.